# native app with ndk not working

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have two devices. One is a HTC Nexus-One running 2.3.6 and another is a LG Optimus V running 2.2.2. The project has a jni library that i am building using android ndk.
The application installs and runs without any issues on the Nexus-One device but it crashes on the LG-device with the following error:

```
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library filters-jni not found
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:466)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     at com.test.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:427)
06-19 16:20:57.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3044):     ... 15 more
```

My make file (Android.mk) looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := filters-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := filters.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFPM_ARM -ffast-math -O3 -Wall
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -ldl
# for native audio
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lOpenSLES
# for logging
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
# for native asset manager
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,cpufeatures)
```

And my Application make file just has a single line

```
    APP_ABI := all
```

What gives, i am unable to understand. Thanks for your suggestions all.

Comment: Most likely it happens because native libs won't get copied to device if it's architecture is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSLES library is available only from Android 2.3.

See `docs/STABLE-APIS.html` file in NDK distribution for list of libraries available for  Android versions.

Comment: i think this is the issue...i will try on another 2.3.x device :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Application.mk file and see what happens:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

This gives the device three .so to choose from whichever it prefers

Comment: sorry. it did not help. "APP_ABI := all" actually generates all the three .so